# What library can I use to implement event driven programming in Python?

Tags: python

Maybe something like Django signals that doesn't depend on Django.

Django signals can be used to [clear cache on saving a model](http://larrymyers.com/articles/4/django-signals-and-caching), I'm trying to do the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want a library like [PyDispatcher](http://pydispatcher.sourceforge.net/) for signal registration and dispatching rather than an event-loop for networking.

Answer (score 7):

- [eventlet](http://eventlet.net/)
- [Twisted](http://www.twistedmatrix.com)
- [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/)
- [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) (either forked or based on eventlet's design)

Of the four, eventlet is probably the quickest to pick up and easiest to use - you don't have to modify a lot of your code to make it event-based in the model of eventlet. It basically does some wrapping of the built-in libraries of python, and can do some runtime monkey patching of your code to make it event-based.

Answer (score 3):

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) is for event-driven networking.

Comment: @Satoru.Logic - it's a framework, for event-driven network programming.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest PySide/PyQt with the signal/slot paradigm. It's quite a big dependency but it's well documented, steel hard tested, thread safe and easy to use.